# Apache equivalent of Nginx

Tags: server, apache2, nginx

I have the following Nginx configuration, but I need to convert it to be compatible with Apache. I have almost zero experience in networking and have no clue where to begin.

```
location ^~ /static {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/static/;
}
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me some hints.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty self-explanatory... ([Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html))

Your equivalent command syntax in Apache would basically be, I believe, something like this:

```
ProxyPass "/static" "http://127.0.0.1:8501/static/"
```

(You may also have to do `"/static/" possibly, but I would have to do further testing.)

Alternatively, this may be what you want instead:

```
<Location "/path/to/docroot/static">
    ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:8501/"
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What about the regex part? "^~"

Comment: @Blademaster `^~` is processed as non-regex.  From the [NGINX docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location): `If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.`